# Reload function fails to erase removed variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I am trying to access variables from a *module* that is being modified while the main *script* runs by using *reload*. But the *reload* function fails to erase the variables that have been removed from the *module*. How to force python to erase them ?

Here is my code

My *module.py* :

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

My main *scipt.py* :

```
import time
from importlib import reload

import module

while True:
    reload(module)
    print('------- module reloaded')
    try:
        print('a: ', module.a)
    except AttributeError:
        print('a: ', 'undefined')
    try:
        print('b: ', module.b)
    except AttributeError:
        print('b: ', 'undefined')
    try:
        print('c: ', module.c)
    except AttributeError:
        print('c: ', 'undefined')

    time.sleep(5)
```

As expected, if I run my *script* with python (3.5.1) I get the output:

```
------- module reloaded
a:  1
b:  2
c:  undefined
```

But I get an unexpected behavior, when I change the *module.py* as following:

```
# a = 1
b = 3
c = 4
```

I have the following output:

```
------- module reloaded
a:  1
b:  3
c:  4
```

This means that *reload* correctly updated the value of *b* and added the new variable *c*. But it failed to erase the variable *a* that has been removed from the *module*. It seems to only perform updates on the variables that are found in the new version of the *module*. How to force the *reload* function to erase removed values ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What happens if you assign the return value of `reload()` to something, and then do the same checks on the returned value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `reload` is implemented with code that, roughly, `exec`s the current version of the module code in the existing cached module's namespace. The reason for doing this is that `reload` is intended to have a global effect; `reload(module)` doesn't just reload it for *you*, it changes every other module's personally imported copy of `module`. If it created a *new* module namespace, other modules would still have the old module cached; while erasing the contents of the old module before `exec`ing might help, it would risk breaking already imported submodules of a package, trigger race conditions (where a thread might see `module.a` before and after the `reload`, but it would mysteriously disappear for a moment during the `reload`), etc.

As [the docs note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload):

> When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. *If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, the old definition remains.*

There are workarounds that bypass this safety mechanism if you absolutely must do it. The simplest is to simply remove the module from the module cache and reimport it, rather than `reload`ing it:

```
import sys  # At top of file

del sys.modules['module']
import module
```

That won't update any other importers of the module (they'll keep the stale cache), but if the module is only used in your module, that'll work.

Another approach that *might* work (untested, and it's kind of insane) would be to explicitly delete all the public names from the module before `reload`ing with something like:

```
# Intentionally done as list comprehension so no modification to module's globals dict
# occurs while we're iterating it
# Might make sense to use dir or iterate module.__all__ if available instead of using vars;
# depends on design
for name in [n for n in vars(module) if not n.startswith('_')]:
    try:
        delattr(module, name)
    except Exception:
        pass  # Undeletable attribute for whatever reason, just ignore and let reload deal with it
reload(module)  # Now exec occurs in clean namespace
```

That would avoid the stale cache issue, in exchange for insanity.

Really, the answer is "don't use a design that depends on production `reload`ing"; if the module is just data, store it as a JSON file or the like and just reparse it (which is generally *much* cheaper than what the Python import machinery goes through to import a module).

Comment: What about something like `module.__dict__.clear()`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: That might work (`vars(module).clear()` is what I'd prefer to avoid direct access to dunders, but same effect). I avoided it largely because there are module attributes that are important to the loader itself that may be needed by the `reload` mechanism (`__spec__`, `__loader__` and `__package__` are a few, and I didn't feel like trawling the docs to make sure I didn't miss any others), and blowing them away could break the `reload` itself.

Comment: To give you some context, my app enables users to modify portions of code. Then, I first designed the main process by making it reload modified modules (that contains not only variables but also functions, classes, ...), instead of loading JSON files. Thank you for your clear answer, it will help me re-design the whole thing.

Comment: @DareYang: You may want to explain more of this. If the app is running in any semi-privileged context (e.g. on a web server) allowing the users to execute code is the definition of a security problem; even if it's running locally, under their own credentials, it's going to be quite difficult to make this stable (one user typo, and the whole thing comes crashing down).

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reload):

> When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. **If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, the old definition remains.**

Generally, `reload` is meant for convenience within interactive interpreter sessions; it is not really meant to be used in real scripts.  You should probably re-think your design.  (e.g. is there a reason that `module` can't be a regular text file?)